# jquery appendTo form

Tags: jquery, appendto

jquery

```
$(function(){
 $('#4').click(function() {
 $('<input name="if4" type="text" value="other price>"').appendTo('form');
   });
 });
```

html

```
    <form>
< input name="name" type="text" value="Enter your name" /><br />
< input name="contacts" type="text" value="Contact info" /><br />
< select name="services">
< option value="1">1</option>
< option value="2">2</option>
< option value="3">3</option>
< option id="4" value="Other">4</option>
< /select><br />
< textarea name="description">Description</textarea><br />
< /form>
```

What i want to do:

When i press on option value nr 4, there appears is new input field, this thing works fine.

But how can I to change order where input field gonna appear, because now it appears after textfield, how can i put it after  ?

Thank you

Comment: Note that it's invalid to start an ID with a number.

Comment: Just as a quick note, valid HTML id attributes cannot start with a numerical character.

Comment: I just wrote numbers for an example, wont use them anywhere :)

Answer (score 6):

```
// Inserts last in any <form>
$('<p>Test</p>').appendTo('form');

// Inserts first in any <form>
$('<p>Test</p>').prependTo('form');

// Inserts right before any <textarea> in any <form>
$('<p>Test</p>').insertBefore('form textarea');

// Inserts right after any <textarea> in any <form>
$('<p>Test</p>').insertAfter('form textarea');
```

Comment: Ohhh, thank you very much :)) did not know about these tags :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want something like this. Note the changed id for the option, and the id added to the select element, to allow positioning of the new input element:

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#opt4').click(function() {
        $('<input name="if4" type="text" value="other price">').insertAfter('#services');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="Enter your name" /><br />
    <input name="contacts" type="text" value="Contact info" /><br />
    <select id="services" name="services">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option id="opt4" value="Other">4</option>
    </select><br />
    <textarea name="description">Description</textarea><br />
</form>
```